# Oracle Fusion Cloud and logging from Groovy scripts

Tags: oracle, groovy, oracle-fusion-apps

We have some Groovy-scripts triggered on various objects (ServerScripts). These triggers produce unexpected results at times so we're wondering if we can log this to file, or specifically the print statements they contain?

I've read a bit in the Oracle docs and it seems Groovy-scripts also can call REST resources. Should we try and set up this logging to somewhere else, like a Seq-server? What's the "best practice" here?

The scripts aren't big, mostly switch statements, but it would be really helpful to have traceability.

Our system is Oracle Fusion Cloud Applications 22B (11.13.22.04.0)

Br, Mya

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use print() and println() to output text messages to the Groovy Diagnostic Log Messages.

See: [Groovy Scripting Reference: Printing and Viewing Diagnostic Messages](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/applications-common/23a/cgsac/printing-and-viewing-diagnostic-messages.html#u30004054)

And yes, you can also use REST APIs to call some external/centralized logging service.  You might even consider Oracle's OCI Logging service, which is very scalable, robust, and feature-rich for aggregating and reporting on logs from multiple sources.

See [Oracle Cloud Infrastructure Logging Service](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Logging/Concepts/loggingoverview.htm)